# Correct use case of String parameter in SetQuery function of SolrQuery?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have q

```
queryString = "select?wt=json&rows=0&indent=true&facet=true&q=*:*&facet=true&facet.field=outcome_type"
```

If queried like :

```
http://x.x.x.x:8983/solr/abc/queryString
```

it works. here abc is a core.

Now I would like to execute it programmatically, and using the following approach :

```
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setQuery(queryString);
    QueryResponse resp = server.query(query);
```

here queryString as defined above, but it return the following error :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException:
>   undefined field text

What I am missing  here ? Or I need to build the query by set functions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see few problems in your tentative.

1. You should not pass entire query string with the `setQuery` method. For almost each parameter available in query string there is a corresponding method in `SolrQuery` class.
2. `SolrQuery` does not support `json` format, SolrJ only supports the `javabin` and `xml` formats, I suggest to not specify any `wt` parameter.

So, you should use `setQuery` method only for `q` parameter:

```
query.setQuery("*:*");
```

For remaining parameters, the easiest way is use `add` method:

```
query.add("rows", "0");  // instead of setRows(0)
query.add("indent", "true"); 
query.add("facet", "true"); // ... setFacet(true)
query.add("facet.field", "outcome_type"); // ... addFacetField("outcome_type")
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have used following approach to execute the query and it worked:

```
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setQuery(queryString);
    query.setFacet(true);
    query.set("wt", "json");
    query.set("indent",true);
    query.setRows(0);
    query.addFacetField("outcome_type");
    QueryResponse resp = server.query(query);
```

[image]