# Apache Solr search a string in the entire collection without specifying the field name

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am looking for a way to search the given string in the entire collection. I referred [Correct use case of String parameter in SetQuery function of SolrQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972147/correct-use-case-of-string-parameter-in-setquery-function-of-solrquery/35005559#35005559)

The provided example works for the scenario like this: `query.setQuery("fieldName":"value")` but it is not working for `query.setQuery("*value*")`. In my case, I don't want to provide the name of the field and it should search the entire collection no matter the field name which has this value. Is there any other way for this scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search whole solr index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449727/how-to-search-whole-solr-index)

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy field named `"text"` in the `schema.xml` and copy all the fields to it.

```
<copyField source="field1" dest="text"/>
```

In order to set default search field in solrconfig.xml file under /query request handler or as IntParams.

```
<requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
   <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
     <str name="wt">json</str>
     <str name="indent">true</str>
     <str name="df">text</str>
   </lst>
</requestHandler>

<initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell,/browse">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="df">text</str>
  </lst>
</initParams>
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to achieve it through Java coding without making any configuration changes. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I don't think so...you have to create a field as above then you can query to that field using java...

Comment: Thanks for the info! I followed the above steps exactly by modifying just "filed1" with whatever the fields are there in my collection. I didn't change other configurations. But still facing the below exception:                                     
Can't load schema  
 C:\\solr-7.6.0\\server\\solr\\locations\\conf\\schema.xml: copyField dest :'text' is not an explicit field and doesn't match a dynamicField.",

Comment: You don’t have any field with “text” name, only field type with “text” name. Try to have a field with name text and you may need to add a type to it as per your requirement...something like..<field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

Comment: Okay. I have two fields in the document as: locationType and description. So i followed your steps as <field name="searchFields" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
  <copyField source="locationType" dest="searchFields"/>
  <copyField source="description" dest="searchFields"/>
  <defaultSearchField>searchFields</defaultSearchField>. Now I am seeing the issue as:Setting defaultSearchField in schema not supported since Solr 7

Comment: <defaultSearchField> is been deprecated and hence follow the follow the above step provided in the answer. The error itself mentions it